# Raw pointer of array and pointer of slice in Rust

Tags: arrays, pointers, rust, slice

I'm trying to better understand Rust's raw pointers, and I thought the following code would fail (sorry for possible UB) [[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=545eee71a506055d4e0bf9eebb15983d)]:

```
fn main() {
    println!("size of * const u32 ->{}", std::mem::size_of::<* const u32>());
    println!("size of * const [u32;13] ->{}", std::mem::size_of::<* const [u32;13]>());
    println!("size of * const [u32] ->{}", std::mem::size_of::<* const [u32]>());
    let x = 1u32;
    let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13u32];
    let px: * const u32 = &x;
    let parr: * const [u32;13] = &arr;
    let slice: &[u32] = &arr;
    let pslice: * const [u32] = slice;
    unsafe { println!("px -> {:?}", px.as_ref()) };
    unsafe { println!("parr -> {:?}", parr.as_ref()) };
    unsafe { println!("pslice -> {:?}", pslice.as_ref()) };
    //
    println!("How could this work:");
    let pslice2: * const [u32] = parr; // How could this work ?
    unsafe { println!("pslice2 -> {:?}", pslice2.as_ref()) }; // How could this work ?
}
```

But it worked even with miri:

```
Standard Error

   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.16s
     Running `/playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo-miri runner target/miri/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/playground`

Standard Output

size of * const u32 ->8
size of * const [u32;13] ->8
size of * const [u32] ->16
px -> Some(1)
parr -> Some([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
pslice -> Some([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
How could this work:
pslice2 -> Some([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
```

I am not surprised with the fact that slice pointer is sized 16 while array pointer is sized 8, because the type does not include the size of the data. But why code `let pslice2: * const [u32] = parr;`, following `let parr: * const [u32;13] = &arr;`, is accepted and why `pslice.as_ref()` produce some data?

Comment: Why wouldn't it, this works even when you replace every `* const` with `&` and remove the `as_ref` calls. Which of the [behaviours considered undefined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) do you think this triggers?

Comment: In general, I am not entirely sure about possible UB, when I make a new use of unsafe. Note that even this document mentions that the "list is not exhaustive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it could seem weird to initialise `pslice2`, a fat pointer (address+size), from `parr`, a simple pointer (address only), because the *size* information missing in `parr` is necessary for `pslice2`.

But this *size* information is known by the compiler (as a constant, not stored anywhere in a variable); that's why `parr` enables accessing all the elements in the array.
Then, during the initialisation of `pslice2`, the «missing» *size* information is simply provided by the compiler (the constant is stored inside the fat pointer).
Once it's done, `pslice2` is a fully functional fat pointer (address+size) which enables accessing all the elements in the array.

Comment: The precise method by which this works is called [unsized coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions) and [applies to raw pointers as well as references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types), [arrays implement `Unsize<[T]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html)